# Fantasy novel series where dragon fight alongside humans in wars

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for a fantasy novel series where the male lead is a young boy who fights alongside a bipedal non-flying dragon in the army.

The army has military units that are formed by these dragons who are all partnered with a boy. These units are like the shock units of the army not unlike tanks of modern days.

The series takes place over a period of time as the boy grows up beside his dragon.

The dragons have the power of speech and uses weapons, shields and wear armor similar to men.

Comment: Any other information you know, like when you read it and/or when it was written?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possibly ["Bazil Broketail"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazil_Broketail) (1992) by Christopher Rowley, which is the first in the series. The dragons were bipedal (I believe the wings were specifically amputated) and used enormous swords. The title character fought alongside a boy named Relkin and the series follows him as he matures.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Not the querent, but it was bugging me not being able to remember this one.

Comment: I kind of want to read this just to figure out why the dragons wouldn't be resentful for losing their wings.

Comment: @DoubleDouble: The answer is mistaken.  The wyverns' wings weren't amputated; they were *vestigal* and useless.  One of the dragons in the army is a wild dragon who used to be able to fly until his wings were mutilated in combat, but the rest of them never had even the potential to fly.

Comment: Thanks. Been trying to find the series for sometime. I read the first few books when I was younger, the series was old even back then. The series stand out to me from the way they portray dragons, not quite the norm.

Comment: I guess my memory was a bit rusty after nearly a quarter century re: the wings.